# I'm trying to take the data from an API call below and make individual objects for display, but I can't figure out a path forward

Tags: angular, api

For example, TMDB sends query results like the screenshots below. Each index (0,1,2,etc.) is an array containing information about a movie. My goal is to extract the data so that each "result" or movie can be used for its own purpose and be displayed. Any ideas / concepts I can use to achieve this?

I'm building the application in Angular

```
   import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
        import { CinemaServiceService } from './services/cinema-service.service';
        import { IMovie } from './Interfaces/iMovie';
    
    
    

    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
    import { CinemaServiceService } from './services/cinema-service.service';
    import { IMovie } from './Interfaces/iMovie';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'connactor-app';
    
      data : IMovie[] = [];
    
      constructor(private cinema: CinemaServiceService){
    
        this.cinema.getData().subscribe(movies => {console.log(movies)})
      }
    
      searchMovies(e: any)
      {
        var query: string = e.target.value;
    
        this.cinema.getQuery(query).subscribe(movies => {this.data = movies;
        console.log(this.data);
        this.extractQuery(this.data)})
      }
    
      extractQuery(movies:any)
      {
        let sample = movies;
        for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
          console.log(movies.results[i].popularity, movies.results[i].original_title)
          this.data = movies.results[i];
          sample = movies.results[i];
          console.log(this.data)
        }
        
        console.log(sample.popularity)
      }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Show some code

Comment: @BojanKogoj - I've added some code from one of the components but I think it will cause more confusion than help because I'm learning as I go. Most of the code is just for testing outcomes